# Is a tcp port number somehow used as a pointer to memory?

Tags: tcp

I'm trying to understand ports on a low-level.  I've been moved from SF and google did no good so hopefully this will be on-topic as low-level programming (it should be).

Ports are just numbers used to access a program/service.  The only way I can see this implemented is by using the port number to send data to an address space (stack?) allocated for specific use by the program/service.  Hence the program/service is looking, a.k.a. "listening", for specific data (protocol-specific) in that address space or "port."  Is this anywhere close to being correct?

Comment: Ports are layer-4 addresses for some layer-4 protocols, just like an IPv4 address is a layer-3 address for IPv4. From [RFC 793](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt): "_To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of addresses or ports within each host. Concatenated with the network and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a socket. A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection. That is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple connections._"

Comment: @ron maupin yes but how is that socket made unique on a low-level?  Could be data sent through the socket is written to a unique adress space on either host using the relevant ports.  An adress space that is only accessible to the end application the port was assigned to.  This seems logical and I'm hoping to get details on the implementation.

Comment: this would depend on the OS in question not networking in general.

Comment: @jim b I can't see the paradigm shifting between os.  Apparrently questions here have to be business related so im hoping to get this move to SO as a low-level programming question

Comment: Because it depends on the kernel on question.  Some limit access per app, some don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hence the program/service is looking, a.k.a. "listening", for specific data (protocol-specific) in that address space or "port."

No, not really.  The most important piece of the puzzle here is the kernel.  When a program "opens a listener on a port", in reality that's a call into the kernel to say "I want to listen on this port".  The kernel is going to remember that, probably in some kind of lookup table.

When a packet arrives, it's the kernel's job to handle the receipt of that packet, parse it, and route the payload to the correct place.  At this point, the kernel is going to lookup which program is registered for that port, and tell it about the new data that has arrived.  That's a complex process, because the program might be asleep (blocked waiting for new data) or it might be running some other code, in which case the new data needs to be queued.

The main point to take away is that your userspace program isn't "listening".  It's up to the kernel to decide when it runs and whether to wake it.  The port number in your original question becomes a lookup into a table that the kernel keeps.

Comment: great answer, I may have additional questions but for now: is the corresponding information to the port in the lookup table the actual address of where the data was stored in memory?  Is an interrupt used to wakeup the program and can it be used to stop a current process (so data doesnt have to be queued)?

Comment: Are you asking about a real time OS or one if the maistream ones.  Your asking about implementation details without an OS

Comment: I won't make you go into a specific os, I think I'm starting to get just how much the implementaion can differ between them

Answer (score -1):

You can think of it like an array index.  That's really as far as you need to go into the details.

Comment: An index in an array of ports?  Is the array used just to store the port number as a reference or is the actual index another array with predefined indexes (for the actual data) relevant to the protocol?

Comment: ill reword that last bit: is the index another array containing the data that is being transmitted?  If so are predefined keys or indexes used to separate the various types of data used in the protocol?

Comment: The kernel uses it as an index to figure out if anyone needs to know about the packet coming in.  You can think of it as there being an array of pointers to functions and the port number is the index to that array and the kernel will call the function at that index.

Comment: How it's actually done depends on the OS and isn't really relevant for most people, unless you're writing a networking stack.